# Optimal way to paginate in symfony 4

Tags: reactjs, php, api, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building an API and I would like to know what is the best way to paginate in symfony (v4) and doctrine ORM.

I've used some bundles such as knp paginator and Pagerfanta,but I'm asking because I'm concerned with performance when we have much data in the DB.
would't be better to use Doctrine's Paginator and implements a pagination by myself ?

thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's hard to answer if you didn't mention how much data you expect.

For now, I would simply use `whiteoctober/Pagerfanta`.

I use `Pagerfanta` to paginate results of **~200 000 000 records** from single Postgres table.

There are no performance issues.

It is also used in official [**Symfony 4 demo**](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/composer.json#L31).

Implementing your own, more efficient paginator - to me will always sound like a great idea (and challenge). But you won't be able to check it's efficiency without having expected amount of data.

Comment: i'll go with the whiteoctober/Pagerfanta , i just wanted to have feedback from people concerning performance, 200 Millions is okay data.

Comment: I've had the same discussion with a friend years ago... we didn't find a better solution than the existing ones.

Comment: Pagerfanta is not in my Symfony 4.3 demo project. Instead, there's a pagination helper class wrapped around a Doctrine Paginator object, solely to tackle queries that contain 'having' by enabling OutputWalker. Not gonna lie, I don't know what that's all about. Pagerfanta is also not in the link which atm points to Symfony 5. That said, Pagerfanta looks good at a first glance.